# scroll to see pre tags content

Tags: html, css

I have a `pre` tag inside a wrapper `div`. I have a bunch of text content inside the `pre` tag. What I want is once the `pre` tags height is taller than the wrapper I want to scroll to see the hidden text content inside the pre tag. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: salmon;
}

.wrapper pre {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: sandybrown;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
    blah
    blah
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you have an `absolute` position in the `pre` tag?

Comment: @VijayHardaha I want to position the pre container to the bottom of wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: salmon;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.wrapper pre {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: sandybrown;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
    blah
    blah
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont need `position:absolute` in this case because postion absolute takes the element out of html flow. i just removed the position absolute and gave parent `overflow-Y: scroll;`
if you want to push the `pre` to the bottom you have to use `position:relative` and push from the top like `top:500px;` meaning push 500px from the top

```css
  .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 90vh;
        width: 50vw;
        overflow-Y: scroll;
        background-color: salmon;
    }

    .wrapper pre {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        top: 500px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: sandybrown;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <pre>
    blah
    blah
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
    check 
    test 
    check 
    test
  </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: ok that fixes the scroll issue but I want to position the pre tag to the bottom of wrapper?

Comment: i have updated the answer you can check now.hope i helped